# Icone e Texto em menu de ActionBar

Tags: java, android

Como posso sempre exibir o ícone com o texto em um botão na ActionBar?

Fiz assim:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_confirmar"
        android:title="Confirmar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_confirmar"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />

</menu>
```

O problema, é que só está exibindo o texto quando a tela está em Landscape(deitada). Em Portrait(em pé) tem espaço suficiente para aparecer o texto, só que não aparece.

Comment: Vc tem algum layout específico para Landscape? Algo como uma pasta res/layout-land e xml's lá dentro? Se sim, verifique se vc não está usando este menu somente no layout em Landscape.

Comment: Não tenho menu para Landscape não, uso o mesmo tanto para Landscape como para Portrait.